# Service with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-service, android-asynctask

I have heard that it isnt good to have an async task in a service.

Is it really necessary for an `AsyncTask` or just `onStartCommand()`?

I am wondering because I have a `Service` with an `AsyncTask` that is launched by an alarm. And it launches the `Service` more than once; it's only supposed to launch once.

Could this be the reason?

EDIT:

Here is how i set up the alarm.

```
    String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(alarm);

    Intent Aintent = new Intent("REFRESH_THIS");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Aintent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() , AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a long-running operation in a service, consider using [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), it will launch and manage a background thread for you. And it has the added benefit that it shuts itself down when finished automatically. You could achieve something similar with an `AsyncTask`, but an `IntentService` will do the right thing.

As for your other question, the service being launched multiple times has nothing to do with the `AsyncTask`. If your alarm runs multiple times, it will launch multiple instances of your service. There is, AFAIK, really no way to make a singleton service automatically. You could check if it's running before launching, or set a preferences flag (error prone), but the preferred way is to have short-lived services launched every time you need to do something, and shut themselves when done. `IntentService` fits this pattern nicely.

Answer (score 5):

There is no bad thing if you want to use `AsyncTask` in service.
It is good if you are using asynctask in service because **service runs on Main Thread** so that if you are using  long process from service it can slow your UI.

You can also create Thread and work in that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to having more control around threads and tasks, specially if you need to perform different ones in a certain order. There is a nice approach to manage the whole system by using queues, thread pool executors, runnables/callables and a service.
http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/07/02/theres-life-after-asynctasks-in-android/