# Service after being started by the broadcast Receiver,how to run AsynTask in that service?

Tags: android

I want to start a service which will send geo location to the server,after a fixed interval of time (using Alarm service). ie, Service after being started by the broadcast Receiver, how to run AsynTask in that service ?

I tried but I am getting this error ::`caused by:java.lang.RuntimeException:can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare`

I have made following code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Start periodic service.
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Intent srvIntent = new Intent(context, NoLopper.class);                 //  StartAtBootService

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, srvIntent, 0);
    // Use context argument to access service
    AlarmManager alarm =(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Repeat every 5 seconds
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                            10000, pIntent);                                                        
    }
```

**this is my service class**

```
    public class NoLopper extends Service 
{

    public static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1010/LociServer/HelloWorldServlet";
    String p="50" ;
    String imei="111" ;
    String returnString=null;
    Integer returnedValue=0;



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Service#onCreate()
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate of lopper", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Service#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent, int, int)
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(this, "on comand of lopper", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show();

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
         task.execute(new String[] { url });


         return START_STICKY;
    }


    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) 
          {
             String output = null;

//          for (String url : urls) 
//           {
//              output = getOutputFromUrl(url);                         // a loop
//           }

//        return output;
//       }

//      private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) 
//      {
//          String output = null;


            try 
            {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                //ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);


                try {


                    String lat="latitude valueee";
                    String lng ="put convereted double into string of latlng variables" ;

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramlat", lat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paramlng", lng));
                //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Gender", gender));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));    // namevaluepair variable are being senddd as entity


                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);  //request the request To execute;; httpRequest variable can be used in future ,ie can be given a warning to the user back
                   // String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, res);

                Toast.makeText(r.fn.sender.NoLopper.this, "from getxmTAsk inner try block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();   //getting the responsed data ;called entites means onject
                    output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);




                      }//end of inner try block



                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }



            } //end of outer try block



            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

            }

           Toast.makeText(r.fn.sender.NoLopper.this, "after catch block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  


         return output;


         }  //end of getOutputFromUrl method



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output)
        {
            //  tv.setText(output);

            //can be used for camera/turn off the phone keyField intent opening values ,if servlet returns open cam. instruction
        //  Log.d("Helloworld", "ur returned list array "+output.toString());

            Toast.makeText(r.fn.sender.NoLopper.this, "onPost method exe block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }




    }  // end of GetXMLTask
}
```

**log**

```
    05-01 12:29:05.823: W/Trace(867): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-01 12:29:05.823: W/Trace(867): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-01 12:29:05.903: D/gralloc_goldfish(867): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
05-01 12:29:05.943: W/Trace(867): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-01 12:29:05.993: W/Trace(867): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
05-01 12:29:06.803: E/log_tag(867): Error in http connection java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-01 12:29:06.803: W/dalvikvm(867): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:324)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:238)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at r.fn.sender.NoLopper$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(NoLopper.java:157)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at r.fn.sender.NoLopper$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(NoLopper.java:1)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-01 12:29:06.843: E/AndroidRuntime(867):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: please tell me where  im wrong.

Comment: Now this is a proper way to ask a question. Please post the error log if you have any.

Comment: sorry ,actually im newer in this stackoverflow ..
and sorry for my english

Comment: Being new to SO, you might not realize there is a search function, if you did search, you would find this answer asked a few times already - like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577624/service-with-asynctask

Comment: yep, i did too many search , nothing will work !...
actually when i running this progamm, it will work fine but when i put my localhost tomcat server ON , the application got crashed.
and the logcat displays error messages , which i put above

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the UI from doInBackground() which is a non-UI thread. Remove `Toast` messages from doInBackgroud(). You can use `Log` instead to check.

Remove : `Toast.makeText(r.fn.sender.NoLopper.this, "after catch block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`  from `doInBackground()`

Comment: can you tell me ! can i able  to vibrate the phone ,inside the service  , im not able to make vibrations:
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
             Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
            // vib.vibrate(500);

Comment: Can you please post this as a new question and give me the link? That way you would not only get more help from other users as well, but we would also be able to maintain one question per thread. :)

Comment: Also please share any logcat message you  might be getting.